# how to NOT crash the build on TS/lint error in nrwl/nx projects

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, nrwl-nx, nrwl

When there's a TS/lint error, the build crashes ie can't see the UI

[image]

Even tho I have the ENV variables that tell webpack to compile on error:

```bash
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true
```

Ideas to work around that?

Here's all the related info:

```bash
$ npx nx report


 >  NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

   Node : 17.6.0
   OS   : darwin arm64
   yarn : 1.22.18

   nx : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/angular : Not Found
   @nrwl/cypress : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/detox : Not Found
   @nrwl/devkit : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/express : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/jest : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/js : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/linter : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/nest : Not Found
   @nrwl/next : Not Found
   @nrwl/node : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/nx-cloud : 14.2.0
   @nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
   @nrwl/react : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
   @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
   @nrwl/storybook : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/web : 14.4.3
   @nrwl/workspace : 14.4.3
   typescript : 4.7.4
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I hid the error panels from CSS. It's not a solution for the build, only for development. (I ended up migrating to Vite with the @nx/vite plugin.)